# Liferay 6.2 - load portlet from client side

Tags: javascript, liferay-6.2

I am using Liferay 6.2 as my portal platform. my question is if there is a way to load portlet via ajax? providing only the portlet id.

e.g.

this is the portlet info:

```
<portlet>
    <portlet-name>my_portlet</portlet-name>
    <instanceable>false</instanceable>
    <private-session-attributes>false</private-session-attributes>
    <header-portlet-javascript>/js/my_portlet/app.js</header-portlet-
</portlet>

<portlet>
    <portlet-name>my_portlet</portlet-name>
    <display-name>My Portlet</display-name>
    <portlet-class>com.ui.portlets.generic.GenericPortlet</portlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <name>view-template</name>
        <value>/view.jsp</value>
    </init-param>
    <expiration-cache>0</expiration-cache>
    <supports>
        <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
    </supports>
    <portlet-info>
        <title>myportlet</title>
    </portlet-info>
</portlet>
```

i want from the client side (by javascript) to get the render html portlet and also all it's params and included files?

Answer (score 1):

Not a clean way, but i am not aware about anything else.

There's something called as widget URL.

you get it via any portlet's configuration.

[image]

Now load this URL in an iFrame. you will achieve your objective of loading the protlet without refreshing the page.

here's some sample snippet.

```
window.Liferay = window.Liferay || {};

Liferay.Widget = function(options) {
    options = options || {};

    var id = options.id || '_Liferay_widget'
            + (Math.ceil(Math.random() * (new Date).getTime()));
    var height = options.height || '100%';
    var url = options.url
            || 'http://www.liferay.com/widget/web/guest/community/forums/-/message_boards';
    var width = options.width || '100%';

    var html = '<iframe frameborder="0" height="' + height + '" id="' + id
            + '" src="' + url + '" width="' + width + '"></iframe>';
    return html;
}
```